# Protect certain folders in wwwroot with authetication in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-authentication

I have placed few folders having static content in wwwroot.
For some folders i need that user is authenticated to view those.

For this i have added code in Startup like below.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx=>
                {
if(!ctx.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && ctx.Context.Request.Path.Value("admin/manuals"))
                    {
                        ctx.Context.Response.Redirect("/");
                    }
        }
        }
```

Although i am authenticated but i am always getting the isAuthenticated false.
Why i am getting this also..

Also what can be the better way to handle such scenario.

Comment: Hi @Codeone,if my answer helped you,could you accept as answer?It could also help others.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to serve files based on authorization:

The fist way like what you did to configre the static files middleware.

> Although i am authenticated but i am always getting the isAuthenticated false.

Be sure call `UseStaticFiles` after `UseAuthorization`:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();   
//...
```

The second way is to serve them via an action method to which authorization is applied and return a FileResult object:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult BannerImage()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(
        _env.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles", "images", "red-rose.jpg");

    return PhysicalFile(filePath, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization